# Spinner item isn't near the spinner's arrow

Tags: android, spinner

I have a **Spinner**:

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_puncte_castigatoare_precedente"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

with an **ArrayAdapter**:

```
public AdapterSpinner(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                      List<PuncteCastigatoareGlobalBean> values) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    this.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner_dropdown_puncte_castigatoare);
}
```

Where **R.layout.item_spinner_dropdown_puncte_castigatoare** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/text1"
  style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:ellipsize="marquee"
  android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

and **int textViewResourceId** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
android:layout_gravity="end"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

This is my user interface:
[image]

I want that the spinner item to be near the spinner's arrow, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

in the textViewResource you have:
`android:textAlignment="viewEnd"`
and
`android:layout_gravity="end"`

Replace those with:
`android:gravity="end"`

android:gravity means the gravity of the content *within* the view, while android:layout_gravity means the gravity of the view itself inside its parent layout.